# Linq to XML decendant elements

Tags: xml, linq, nodes

i know this is a simple question , so apologies , but i'm new to linq to xml , and am having difficulty with the following :

I have the following XML and am trying to get out all the elements , including the Address elements :

```
<LawCentres>
<LawCentre>
  <LawCentreID>2</LawCentreID>
  <LawCentreName>Test Law Centre</LawCentreName>
  <Address>
    <Address1>Test Address1</Address1>
    <Address2>Test Address2</Address2>
    <Address3>Test Address3</Address3>
 </Address>
</LawCentre>
<LawCentre>
  <LawCentreID>22</LawCentreID>
  <LawCentreName>Secondary Law Centre</LawCentreName>
  <Address>
    <Address1>ADDRESS11</Address1>
    <Address2>ADDRESS21</Address2>
    <Address3>ADDRESS31</Address3>
    <CountryRef>10985</CountryRef>
    <CountyRef>12116</CountyRef>
  </Address>
</LawCentre>
</LawCentres>
```

and i have the following code written , but i am having difficuty extracting the Addresses along with the law centre info:
            XDocument lawCentres = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XML\LawCentres.xml"));

```
        var lawCentreQuery = from c in lawCentres.Descendants("LawCentre")
                             where (int)c.Element("LawCentreID") == lawCentreID
                             select new LawCentre
                             {
                                 LawCentreName = (string)c.Element("LawCentreName"),
                                 LawCentreID = (int)c.Element("LawCentreID"),
                                 LawCentreAddressLine1 = (string)c.Element("Address1"),
                                 LawCentreAddressLine2 = (string)c.Element("Address2"),
                                 LawCentreAddressLine3 = (string)c.Element("Address3"),
                             };
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `(string)c.Element("Address1")` with `(string)c.Element("Address").Element("Address1")`

OR

```
(string)c.Descendants("Address1").FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: The second option works perfect , thanks a million for your help Hasan !

Comment: @Alicia first option had a path error; fixed it. Now that will work too